# Edit Style Attribute of every div in a list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to write a script to help out a colourblind friend of mine.

He's on a page laid out like this:

```
<div class="message-pane-wrapper candy-has-subject">
    <ul class="message-pane">
        <li><div style="color:#700400"></div></li>
        <!-- many more li items -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is use JavaScript to change all of the style tags so the color is the same.

I've tried looping through like this:

```
var div = document.getElementById('message-pane-wrapper candy-has-subject');
var divs = div.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 1) {
   divs[i].style = 'color:#00000';
}
```

But I don't think it's right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna be more specific with your selection: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/aminmeyghani/mcaofpyh/2)

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".message-pane div");
var dd = Array.prototype.slice.call(divs);
dd.forEach(function (div) { div.style.color = "#000" });
```

Answer (score 1):

**[].forEach.call(NodeList) hack**

You should not use blank arrays to iterate through nodelists, nodelists are not arrays for a reason. There is some [excellent information about why not to use this hack](http://toddmotto.com/ditch-the-array-foreach-call-nodelist-hack/).

**The proper way**

This script selects every element in the document, then uses a for loop to iterate through the nodelist and sets the text color for each node to #000

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('*'), element;
    for (var i = 0; element = elements[i]; i++) element.style.color = '#000000';
})();
```

```html
<div class="message-pane-wrapper candy-has-subject">
    <ul class="message-pane">
        <li><div style="color:#700400">Hello World</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you specifically want the div elements within the section mentioned in your question you can use a more specific selector. Please note that using the `*` selector creates quite a bit of overhead on sites with lots of elements, but as it only has to run once on page load, there shouldn't be an issue

```js
(function(){
    "use strict";
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.message-pane-wrapper.candy-has-subject div'), element;
    for (var i = 0; element = elements[i]; i++) element.style.color = '#000000';
})();
```

```html
<div class="message-pane-wrapper candy-has-subject">
    <ul class="message-pane">
        <li><div style="color:#700400">Hello World</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`'message-pane-wrapper candy-has-subject'` is not an ID but two classes. Use `getElementsByClassName` like this:

Either

```
var div = document.getElementsClassName('message-pane-wrapper')[0];
```

… or

```
var div = document.getElementsClassName('candy-has-subject')[0];
```

If there are multiple `div`s with the same classes you’ll have to loop over those as well. Another alternative is to select the element using `querySelectorAll` and loop over that instead.

And you can’t set the `style` attribute like that. Use either

```
divs[i].style.color = '#000000';
```

… or

```
divs[i].setAttribute('style','color:#000000;');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.style` is an object, which means it had different properties which you access using:

```
element.style.color = '#000';
```

---

You can use `.forEach` also to decrease code complexity:

```
var divs = div.getElementsByTagName('div');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function (elem) {
    elem.style.color = '#000';
});
```

Comment: @humble.rumble ahh yes, that would be better word choice. Thanks for the tip